# Do I need to know someone's Apple ID email address to gift them an app?

Tags: ios-appstore, gift

I'd like to send an app from the App Store to somebody as a gift. I have their email address, but I'm not sure if it's the email address associated with their Apple ID.

Do I need to enter their **specific Apple ID email address**, or will they be able to download the gift app if the email gets sent to **any of their email addresses**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the email sent contains a link with a promo code, it's not bound to the email address.

So you can send it to whatever, they'll still be able to get the app gifted.

Comment: I confirmed this by gifting myself an app to the wrong email address. No problems encountered.